# How to help the high schooler (in China) understand what is so great about The Old Man and the Sea?

Tags: ernest-hemingway, the-old-man-and-the-sea

The Old Man and the Sea, the translated version, is a recommended book for high school students nationwide in China (China has nationwide syllabuses). But I find my son and his classmates seem not appreciate the story much. Some common questions they have are: what is so great about this story; why was it awarded a Nobel Prize?

I remember I did not appreciate it either in my 20s. I can see the primary conflict—man vs. nature, I can see some symbolic meanings in the story. I was told the book represented the unique writing style of Hemingway. I then read the English version but because I didn't have enough knowledge about English literature so I don't really appreciate the writing style either.

I guess the doubt is maybe is common among young reader in China, what is so great about the story?

**Update**

Recently I watched [Hemingway | A Film about Ernest Hemingway by Ken Burns and Lynn Novick](https://www.pbs.org/kenburns/hemingway/) on PBS so I have a better understanding about his life. I was amused to see this comment about "the old man and the sea"

[image: Photograph of Edna O'Brien saying, "It's adolescence. It's schoolboy writing"]

A comment I got mentioned an article called "[Why the Hell Are We Still Reading Ernest Hemingway?](https://www.thedailybeast.com/why-the-hell-are-we-still-reading-ernest-hemingway)". It is kind of reassuring to see even the English native speakers have this doubt. And to quote the words about "the old man and the sea"

> The reputation of The Old Man and the Sea (1952) hasn’t fared much
> better. Dwight Macdonald scored easy points when he said it was
> “written in that fake, biblical prose which Pearl Buck used in The
> Good Earth… Miss Buck also got a Nobel Prize out of it.”

Comment: Welcome to Literature! There are really two questions here: (i) what is so great about Hemingway? and (ii) how can you help your son to appreciate The Old Man and the Sea? We can probably answer (i) but I think (ii) may be beyond our powers. I recommend editing the question to focus on (i) and asking (ii) in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1037/the-reading-room) where it's fine to canvas for opinions.

Comment: @GarethRees thank you for your comments. But in this particular question I want to focus on the old man and the sea, e.g. what is so great about the story ? Besides, what is so great about Hemingway is probably too big a topic for Chinese high schoolers.  Does that Make sense? I probably can editing my question, remove the appreciation part.

Comment: Hi I edited my question to focus on the story. Will that make it easy to answer ?

Comment: Thanks for editing, the question might be answerable now. You might want to look at [Anders Österling's 1954 speech](https://www.nobelprize.org/prizes/literature/1954/ceremony-speech/) awarding the Nobel prize to Hemingway, so see the Swedish Academy's reasoning.

Comment: It should be noted that Hemingway is a controversial figure even in the US, and not everyone there thinks he's a great writer or a great man (and of course people argue whether the two are related). For instance: [this article](https://www.thedailybeast.com/why-the-hell-are-we-still-reading-ernest-hemingway) or [Quora](https://www.quora.com/Why-do-so-many-people-hate-Hemingway-as-a-writer).

Comment: @StuartF Thanks for the article "Why the Hell Are We Still Reading Ernest Hemingway"! It is reassuring  to see native speakers also have this doubt! I never understand and never appreciate "The Snows of Kilimanjaro".  After watching https://www.pbs.org/kenburns/hemingway/ I now know some background of the novel, but I still won't re-read it. My question here is about the old man and the sea though, e.g. can young readers understand it ?

Comment: @StuartF He was definitely not a great man in my opinion. My definition about is a great man is like Ernest Shackleton!